# Confused with printing function from this definition

Tags: python, list, linked-list

```
class X:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def linkedlist(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    beg = end = X(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        end.next = X(v)
        end = end.next
    return beg

lst1 = linkedlist(['one', 'two', 'three'])
lst2 = linkedlist(['one', 'three', 'four'])
```

When I print this, i get

```
 print(lst1)
 <__main__.LN object at 0x102957510>
```

I am very confused at what is happening. How am I supposed to call this definition?

Edit:

Using this class/function, I am trying to create this recursive function that returns an output whether the two linked lists are equal or not.

```
def is_same(lst1, lst2):
    if ll1.next.value == [] or ll2.next.value == []:
        return True      
    elif ll1.next.value == ll2.next.value:
        is_same(ll1.next.value, ll2.next.value)
```

I'm not sure how to approach this function, but this is what I attempted to do, but obviously results in an error.

```
a = linkedlist(['a', 'b', 'c''])
b = linkedlist(['a', 'b', 'c'])
c = linkedlist(['c', 'a', 'b'])
```

Calling:

```
 is_same(a, b)
```

should result in True

but

```
 is_same(a, c)
```

should result in False

Answer (score 4):

Because your method `linkedlist` is returning an object of the `X` class, you may want to print `lst1.value` or `list1.next`.

Or create an `__str__` method in your `X` class.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have one of the following to display how you want the class to print out:

`__str__` or `__repr__`

[here are the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Python will print out a default depending on the classes location in memory. In order to customize it you need to define one of those methods inside your class `X`